# PHP system() raises command not found error

Tags: php, shell, command-line, tesseract

Trying to run this script:

```
<?php

   $src  = "./tmp/image1.jpg";
   $dest = "./tmp/image1";
   $out  = "";

   // ob_start();
   $out  = system("tesseract $src $dest");
   // ob_end_clean();

   die($out);
?>
```

It shows a blank script and error log displays: sh: ***tesseract: command not found***

This command works fine on shh though...

Any idea why ?

Comment: the script probably isn't in the $PATH.  Find the full path with `which tesseract` then use that as the command.

Comment: **tesseract** - is your server co-located on Odin?

Comment: not its not co-located on Odin

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll need to provide the full path to the tesseract command on disk (usually`/usr/bin/tesseract`, but this may be different depending on your particular platform/distribution), as the context that PHP executes the command in won't have the relevant default paths set up.

To find out where the command resides, just use `which tesseract` via the shell. (As long as it's actually available without using the full path.)

Comment: @StephaneKouakou No need for thanks. (StackOverflow is all about helping). Hope your project goes well. :-)

Answer (score 4):

"tesseract" path is probably not in the PATH env when run as WWW/PHP user. Try using full path to it.